# cakephp how can i include bootstrap framework css style to my app?

Tags: html, css, templates, cakephp

Anybody has integrated cake php with bootstrap framework/css style ?

I want to be able use advantages of bootstrap in cakephp views : 
like btn's and panels
[bootstrap styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnQyD.png)

I use cakephp 2.10.11
How can i add bootstrap CDN ? or downloaded bootstrap library? where to put it? how to link to it?

Thanks : D

Comment: Read the documentation and use Google. Each point you ask for is covered in the according documentation. You haven't done anything at all on your own if you can't even figure out where to download Bootstrap. You just want to get spoon-feed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use downloaded bootstrap library. Just put your `bootstrap.min.css` 
file inside `/app/webroot/css/` folder.

```
   app/
      webroot/
             css/ <-- here
```

and then use it like below using HtmlHelper

```
<?php echo $this->Html->css("bootstrap.min.css"); ?>
```

**OR**

If you want to use cdn the just add the below code inside head tag of .ctp file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

[Cakephp 2.x  -> HtmlHelper](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html)

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks it was exacly what i was asking : )

Comment: @JakubUjvvary Welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer. It will help others

Answer (score 0):

Download bootstrap css and js files and put them in webroot/css or webroot/js respectively.

Then in `app/View/Elements/header.ctp` file add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo Router::url('/css/bootstrap.min.css', true); ?>">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And in `app/View/Elements/footer.ctp` add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Router::url('/js/bootstrap.min.js', true); ?>"></script>
```

Now you can access bootstrap classes in your code.